# delete Treenode not removed

Tags: treenode

I am developing in Visual Studio 2012 web interface. When I remove a parent node it removes correctly, but when I try to remove a child node the node stays and does not seem to get removed. Both methods shows the same result.

```
Tree1.Nodes.Remove(e.Node);
```

This is a postback method removing the node with e as FineUI.TreeCommandEventArgs.

```
Tree1.Nodes.Remove(Tree1.SelectedNode);
```

This is another method to remove the node. There is no update or refresh method to refresh the tree. Both of which cannot delete a child node.

Another question would be that I want to update the database based on the SelectedNode, the SelectedNodeID contains a string with the ID value, but it exist in a form like fnode1 where I only want the integer value at the end. I want to know how to get just the integer value so I can delete the selected node from the database.

Answer (score 0):

what u need to do is you need to take DefaultNode from Tree and then u have to Remove it. see this.

```
    DefaultMutableTreeNode defaultMutableTreeNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(node_vervesystems);
    model.removeNodeFromParent(defaultMutableTreeNode);
```

that will Work.

Here the Example for the same.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author kishan
 */
public class JTreeRemoveNode extends JFrame{
    public JTreeRemoveNode() throws HeadlessException {
        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        setSize(200, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Address Book");
        String[] names = new String[] {"Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Mallory"};
        for (String name : names) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name);
            root.add(node);
        }

        final JTree tree = new JTree(root);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));

        JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
        removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();

                TreePath[] paths = tree.getSelectionPaths();
                for (TreePath path : paths) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
                    if (node.getParent() != null) {
                        model.removeNodeFromParent(node);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(tree, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(removeButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JTreeRemoveNode().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

hope that will help.